# In Linux, how to audit all npm packages in git repository grouped by their license

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, npm

We have multiple folders with different set of services that uses different package.json. I would like to audit and consolidate the list of packages that is used across all the services and list with their versions.

I collected all the package.json files with the following command.

> find . -type f | grep package.json

I want to read all package.json and dedupe all the packages with their versions and consolidate all the packages into a single list.

Once the list is consolidated, we need to grab their licenses and group the packages with their licenses.

Is there a simple way do all these?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to aggregate? `dependencies`, `devDependencies`, `peerDependencies`, or all. Also, are you considering a unique entry (for deduping) a package/version combo or a package?

Comment: This is for SOX compliance, auditors need all packages using in development and in production (includes dev and peer dependencies too, not one depth, but inluding all depth in node_modules) we are using from open source. I'm personally interested in solving the problem too.

Comment: I would like to classify based on licenses, that way auditors can help to accomodate how we can use it for business purposes.